# Send data fetch from array from page to other page by jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

i have 2 pages, one that send data from form and send data to second page.

the first page is html, and the second is php.

So, my problem is i send data from form to the second page to enter to SQL statement, and i get data from fetch array, how can i send data from second page to first page and put it in div.

my JS that i will send

```
// This function to search aqar
function search_aqar(){

    var city = $('#city').val();
    var aqar_type = $('#aqar_type').val();
    var adv_type = $('#adv_type').val();
    var search_btn = $('#search_btn').val();
    var show_type = $('#show_type').val();

    if (city!='' && aqar_type !='' && adv_type !=''){

    $.ajax({
      url: "request.php?do=search_aqar",
      type: "POST",
      data: {
             city        : city,
             aqar_type  : aqar_type,
             adv_type    : adv_type,
             show_type    : show_type,
             search_btn   : search_btn
          },
      dataType: "json",
      success: function(data){
      if(data.process == "ok"){

      }
      else
      {

      }
      }  
      });
    }
    else
    {

    }
}
```

and i get data to page name `request.php` and put variable to sql statement, i need send data to first page on div

Comment: I believe that on submit, you shouldnt change the page that you are on (action NOT to .php). I think you want a callback on submit, so that when you submit, you do ajaxRequest, the php is executed and you obtain answer (output of that .php process) and you can do what you want with your response. Maybe include your `HTML` with form for clarity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just put a div in your html file like this:

```
<div id="msg"></div>
```

And change this:

```
success: function(data){
  if(data.process == "ok"){

  }
```

To this:

```
success: function(data){
  $('#msg').html(data);  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you may need to return the data as an json_encoded array from your php script and then use

```
success: function(data){
 var variable = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
 $("#yourdiv").html(variable['your_array_identifier']);
}
```

if you are not sending back an array and just a single item then you don't need to return an array and just simply use

```
   success: function(data){
     $("#yourdiv").html(data);
    }
```